# HP Laserjet printers do not work in a specific office network, works in others

Tags: networking, printer, lan, network-printer

We have a HP LJ 3055 at a branch office which stopped printing. Replacement LJ 3055 also didn't work there. RAW, port 9100.

1. Printing problems affect a single LAN. Same printers work in other office.
2. Tried different computers. Sometimes after power cycling the printer a job or 2 go through and then the printer eats the job but only shows Ready or Printing (forever).
3. All computers can ping and access the printers web interface. Web interface command to print font list works when nothing has been printed after power cycling printer. But I cant even get a usage page out after that from the printer menu.
4. Tried using other lan cables, other switch.
5. Non-HP printers do work in that network (port 9100).
6. Tried changing printer IP, also setting fixed (not DHCP).
7. No changes to router configuration, tried restarting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Although you changed the printer IP did you remove and re-add the printer on your client computers so they're aware of the new IP? (you can change the IP through the advanced settings but it's easier to re-add the device). Going to the printer's web interface will always work because you're directly communicating with the device. A client computer needs to re-associate with any new IPs as it caches (by being configured to use) any previous IP.

Comment: I also tried with computers that didn't have HP drivers previously. Yes I changed the IPs on computers - sometimes I could get one job out of the printer from a computer before the printer locks up and needs to be power cycled.